# Display cs cart recently viewed block just beside description div

Tags: cs-cart

I am using cscart4. i want to to display "recently viewed" block and product description part side by side.

I have added recently viewed block in products layout. But product description is in part of "main content" grid. So that recently viewed block displaying under entire product detail block.

finally my question is how can we merge any block with in the template content?

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

You cand do this in 2 ways:

1. Create a new block with smarty support. Add in this capture for product description:

   {**$smarty.capture.$prod_descr** nofilter}
2. Move it with jQuery

   2.1. Create a new block with only one div who has class like this: **class="block-desc"**

   2.2. in index.tpl add this code:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(".block-desc").html($(".ty-product-block__description")); 
       $(".ty-product-block__description").html("");
   </script>
   ```